# How to fix an error while registering PostgreSQL database to ArcGIS Enterprise Server

Tags: postgresql, arcgis-server, database

Software in use is:
ArcMap 10.8.1
ArcGIS Server (Enterprise) 10.8
PostgreSQL 13 + PostGIS 3.1
Windows 10 64bit

I followed a guide to register a PostgreSQL database (PostGIS) to ArcGIS Server. When I try to register the database, it gives an error as in the picture I provided. Connecting to the PostgreSQL database through ArcMap client works flawlessly (I can query, make edits etc.). What can be the problem? I googled for almost an hour without finding anything similar to my error.[image]

Comment: PG 13 is not yet supported by ArcGIS 10.8.1. https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/system-requirements/latest/database-requirements-postgresql.htm  Did you *enable* an Enterprise geodatabase (`sde` schema, etc.) or is this a non-geodatabase registry attempt?

Comment: I didn't know it wasn't supported. I didn't enable an Enterprise geodatabase. I just imported a .gdb file through a console into a PostGIS enabled PostgreSQL DB. Is it important for the registration to ArcGIS Server to work?

Comment: Server can't serve without data store registration. Given that it isn't supported, it's possible that something about PG 13 doesn't play nice w/ AGS, even if it does nominally function from Desktop (PostGIS 3.1 could be the sticking point).

Comment: I meant: Is 'enabling an Enterprise geodatabase' an important step to do in order to make the registration of data store work? I'll try to research some more.
Also I read something about granting privileges to AGS account for the PostgreSQL db. Did I get it wrong? Is it necessary to create the same account and password I use for managing AGS as the one I use to connect to the db? Doesn't make sense to me.
I also read something about AGS site having necessary library files to connect to PostgreSQL. Not sure if this can be of an issue.

Comment: No, an enabled geodatabase isn't required (you couldn't anyway, since there isn't a PG 13 implementation of `sde.ST_Geometry` yet), but if PG13 doesn't *just work*, I don't think it will before 10.9.0.

Comment: So it seems I need to install PG 12.2 which is supported by ArcGIS 10.8.1. Do they mean also ArcGIS Enterprise 10.8.1 is supported?? On the PG download site, I found only version 12.6. Will that work too?

Comment: PG 12.2 is the *minimum*. 12.6 should work fine and is supported.

Comment: I confirm that PG version 12.6 got registered with ArcGIS Server successfully.

Comment: Update: Today I tried to register a database just like I did few weeks ago and an error occured saying: "The connection property set was missing a required property or the property value was unrecognized. Instance not available on server." Just like the error I received while trying to register a PG 13 db.
I generated a .sde file from ArcMap and trying to import it. Gives me the error. It's PG v.12.6. What could have gone wrong?

Comment: No idea. Contact Tech Support.

Comment: Could that be something with the server with AGS installed doesn't have access (cant read) the folder on the computer where PG server runs on?

Comment: ArcGIS never *tries* to read any folders. All access is always through the database's networking protocol.